# Is "Jump if zero" (jz) faster?

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

I was reading [this article](http://0xax.blogspot.com/2014/09/say-hello-to-x64-assembly-part-2.html), and I noticed the `jz` instruction. This got me thinking:

Would the assembly of this code

```
for (int i=max;i!=0;--i){
    //Some operation
}
```

outperform the assembly of this code?

```
for (int i=0;i<max;++i){
    //Some operation
}
```

As long as you don't care that your data gets processed with an increasing `i`, there is no semantic difference. Cache misses shouldn't suffer either, because they can work sequentially either way.

I'm not good enough at assembly to write examples, but I would think that the first example would only use a `jz`. The second would use a `cmp`, then a `jg`, and also require another variable, `max`. The first example would only need the loop counter, because the `0` is implicit.

This may also be something that compilers use to optimize already, but I can imagine cases where it wouldn't be able to make the optimization.

Comment: yeah, i think that depends on the number of cycles required by each different jump instruction.  I don't know off hand, but if you look up the instruction set that you're targeting you should be able to find an enumeration of the number of cycles used by each instruction.

Comment: it might still require a cmp instruction since it is a comparison of a memory location.  the loop counter might also be allocated automatically to a register in later compilers.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22466475

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is comparing to zero faster than comparing to any other number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466117/is-comparing-to-zero-faster-than-comparing-to-any-other-number)

Comment: [Is it faster to count down than it is to count up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2823043/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that we have `cmp a,b`.

The processor will make a temporary subtraction of operands (without affecting their values), setting the flags properly and after this your `jmp` jump operation are evaluated.

So, it's faster in you example to make a `jz`, rather then a `cmp` and a `jmp`.

Comment: i forgot that the decrement would set the zero flag.  good point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider this a largely [solved problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization) with modern compilers. Or if not *solved*, then at least *usually* right, applying heuristics to yield better loop transforms. For x86[-64], there are more important considerations, e.g., does the loop 'body' fit in the instruction cache? Is the jump destination suitably aligned? Is the branch prediction effective?

There are multiple approaches to implementing loops with x86. e.g.,

- Use of the `j[e|r]cxz` instruction, avoiding flags registers - though slower to decode.
- Using `sub` or `add` prior to `j<cond>` rather than `dec` or `inc` to avoid partial flags register stalls.

The `operation` will matter too. is `max` known at compile time?

```
for (int i = 0; i < max / 4; i++)
{
    operation;
    operation;
    operation;
    operation;
}
```

If `operation` is simple enough (e.g., a floating-point operation), it might benefit from this sort of n-way scheduling. If each operation depends on the previous operation, it won't.

Have a look at something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). The `mpn/x86[-64]` directories optimize loops for different micro-architectures. [Agner Fog's optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals) are an excellent resource.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes having the loop count down can free up a register, which will probably be more useful (especially on x86-32, where registers are scarce), than any difference in jump conditions.
**However**, counting down in the loop can prevent auto-vectorisation. If your calculations can be done with SSE/AVX/whatever, you may need to write code like

```
for (i=end; i;){
    i-=4;
    val[i+0] = foo(i);
    val[i+1] = foo(i);
    val[i+2] = foo(i);
    val[i+3] = foo(i);
    }
```

and then you have to make sure `end%4 == 0`, all to save one register.